# I need to make a change in "cmp()" method, so that "'ace" in ranks will be greater than "king"

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

How to change `cmp` method, so that `ace` in ranks will be greater than `king`?

```
class Cards:
    suits = ["clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"]
    ranks = ["narf", "ace",  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "jack", "queen", "king"]


    def __init__(self, suit= 0, ranks = 0):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = ranks

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.ranks[self.rank] + "of" + self.suits[self.suit])

    def cmp(self, other):

        if self.suit > other.suit: return 1
        if self.suit < other.suit: return -1

        # .. if suits are same then check for ranks
        if self.ranks[1] < other.ranks[:]: return 1
        if self.rank > other.rank:   return 1
        if self.rank < other.rank:   return-1

        return 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.cmp(other) == 0

    def __le__(self, other):
         return self.cmp(other) <= 0

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.cmp(other) >= 0
        
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.cmp(other) > 0

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cmp(other) < 0

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.cmp(other) != 0

card1 = Cards(1, 1)
card2 = Cards(1, 13)

print(card1 < card2)
```

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?  From the title it sounds like you already know what needs to be done.

Comment: `self.ranks[1] < other.ranks[:]` doesn't make sense. You can't compare a string with a list. Also, why do you make a copy of the list before comparing it?

Comment: Why don't you just put `ace` after `king` in the `ranks` list?

Comment: Could you add more on what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is?

Comment: You can decorate your class with `functools.total_ordering`; then you only need to define `__eq__` and any one of `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__`, or `__ge__`. The decorator will generate the rest for you.

Comment: it is a task that i am supposed to do, in which modifying the method cmp() will rank ace higher than king. and not change Ranks. self.ranks[1] < other.ranks[:] is the lame part I tried,

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a larger value to `aces` in the `cmp` method, and compare these values instead of the indices.

```
def cmp(self, other):

    if self.suit > other.suit: return 1
    if self.suit < other.suit: return -1

    s_val, o_val = self.ranks, other.ranks
    s_val = float('inf') if s_val == 1 else s_val
    o_val = float('inf') if o_val == 1 else o_val

    if s_val < o_val: return 1
    if s_val > o_val: return 1
    if s_val < o_val: return -1

    return 0
```